# ClassLoader.getSystemResources(String name) cannot find file in Maven managed project

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I'm doing a project managed with Maven. The purpose of the project is to access a `.csv` file and read specific columns from it. I have just started, but run into trouble with the `ClassLoader.getSystemResources(String name)` method which cannot find the resource specified with the name argument. I put the `.csv` file in a the Maven project's `resources` directory.

I think the problem is caused by using Maven to manage the project because I tested the `ClassLoader.getSystemResources(String name)` method in a test program with a working result. I've also tried using other methods to obtain the path of the `.csv' file in my project, but got the same failing result.

Please help me find out what has gone wrong and how to resolve the problem.

Thank you for your help!

The Error message:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toURI()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResource(String)" is null
    at com.wordbankbuilder.NamedColumnBean.getNamedColumnBean (WordbankBuilder.java:80)
    at com.wordbankbuilder.WordbankBuilder.main (WordbankBuilder.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:832)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.879 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-04T11:52:03+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:java (default-cli) on project WordbankBuilder: An exception occured while executing the Java class. Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toURI()" because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResource(String)" is null -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

The code and POM file are as follows:

The main class - WordbankBuilder:

```
package com.wordbankbuilder; 
 
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import com.opencsv.*;
import com.opencsv.bean.*;

public class WordbankBuilder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         NamedColumnBean ncb = new NamedColumnBean();
         ncb.getNamedColumnBean();
         
         System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
    }
 }

 class CsvBean {}

 class NamedColumnBean extends CsvBean {
      @CsvBindByName(column = "word")
      private String name;

      @CsvBindByName(column = "phonetic")
      private String phonetic;

      @CsvBindByName(column = "translation")
      private String translation;

      public String getName () {
         return this.name;
      }
      public String getPhonetic () {
         return this.phonetic;
      }
      public String getTranslation () {
         return this.translation;
      }
      public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
      }
      public void setPhonetic(String phonetic) {
         this.phonetic = phonetic;
      }
      public void setTranslation(String translation) {
         this.translation = translation;
      }

      public List<CsvBean> namedColumnBeanBuilder (Path path, Class clazz) {
         // read and parse ecdict.mini.csv
         CsvTransfer csvTransfer = new CsvTransfer();
         ColumnPositionMappingStrategy ms = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
         ms.setType(clazz);

         try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader).withType(clazz).withMappingStrategy(ms).build();
            csvTransfer.setCsvList(cb.parse());
         } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            ioEx.printStackTrace();
         }

         return csvTransfer.getCsvList();
      }

      public List<CsvBean> getNamedColumnBean () {
         Path path = null;

         try {
            URI resURI = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/src/main/resources/ecdict.mini.csv").toURI();
            path = Paths.get(resURI);
            path = Paths.get("ecdict.mini.csv");
         } catch (URISyntaxException uriEx) {
            uriEx.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
         }
         
         return namedColumnBeanBuilder(path, NamedColumnBean.class);
      } 
 }
```

The CsvTransfer class - CsvTransfer.java

```
package com.wordbankbuilder; 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvTransfer {

    private List<String[]> csvStringList;

    private List<CsvBean> csvList;

    public CsvTransfer() {}

    public List<String[]> getCsvStringList() {
        if (csvStringList != null) return csvStringList;
        return new ArrayList<String[]>();
    }

    public void addLine(String[] line) {
        if (this.csvList == null) this.csvStringList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.csvStringList.add(line);
    }

    public void setCsvStringList(List<String[]> csvStringList) {
        this.csvStringList = csvStringList;
    }

    public void setCsvList(List<CsvBean> csvList) {
        this.csvList = csvList;
    }

    public List<CsvBean> getCsvList() {
        if (csvList != null) return csvList;
        return new ArrayList<CsvBean>();
    }
}
```

The POM.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.wordbankbuilder</groupId>
    <artifactId>WordbankBuilder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.wordbankbuilder.WordbankBuilder</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```